# How do I get git to default to ssh and not https for new repositories

Tags: git, github, ssh

These days when I create a new repository on GitHub on the setup page I get:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/nikhilbhardwaj/abc.git
git push -u origin master
```

And whenever I have to push a commit I need to enter my GitHub username and password.

I can manually change that to

```
git@github.com:nikhilbhardwaj/abc.git
```

in the `.git/config`. I find this quite irritating - **is there some way I can configure git to use SSH by default?**

Comment: I think @MoOx's answer is probably most consistent with what you are seeking. The `insteadOf` trick has been around since at least 2012. Also see [How to convert `git:` urls to `http:` urls](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1722807/608639).

Answer (score 456, accepted):

#### Set up a repository's origin branch to be SSH

The GitHub repository setup page is just a suggested list of commands (and GitHub now suggests using the HTTPS protocol). Unless you have administrative access to GitHub's site, I don't know of any way to change their suggested commands.

If you'd rather use the SSH protocol, simply add a remote branch like so (i.e. use this command *in place* of GitHub's suggested command). To modify an existing branch, see the next section.

```
$ git remote add origin git@github.com:nikhilbhardwaj/abc.git
```

---

#### Modify a pre-existing repository

As you already know,  to switch a pre-existing repository to use SSH instead of HTTPS, you can change the remote url within your `.git/config` file.

```
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    -url = https://github.com/nikhilbhardwaj/abc.git
    +url = git@github.com:nikhilbhardwaj/abc.git
```

A shortcut is to use the `set-url` command:

```
$ git remote set-url origin git@github.com:nikhilbhardwaj/abc.git
```

---

#### More information about the SSH-HTTPS switch

- ["Why is Git always asking for my password?"](https://help.github.com/articles/why-is-git-always-asking-for-my-password) - GitHub help page.
- [GitHub's switch to Smart HTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11197576/github-uses-smart-http) - relevant StackOverflow question
- [Credential Caching for Wrist-Friendly Git Usage](https://github.com/blog/1104-credential-caching-for-wrist-friendly-git-usage) - GitHub blog post about HTTPS, and how to avoid re-entering your password

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about them making smart https the default.

Comment: This may be good for Windows users, but on Linux it was quite a step backwards: ssh always worked, and the new password caching for Smart HTTPS works only on Windows. Theres a note on *"Where's the Mac version?"* but not a **single** word for linux users.

Comment: I should add that, this method does not interfere with github's mac client at all. Change it and you can both use command line and gui version(github's client) of git without a problem.

Comment: Now that GitHub is deprecating password access ([see here](https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/)), it seems like this answer needs to be part of their official documentation somewhere. Is it already there?

Comment: For anyone whom this didn't work check your global git config at ~/.gitconfig. I had an insteadOf url command forcing https access.

Answer (score 345):

- GitHub

  ```
  git config --global url.ssh://git@github.com/.insteadOf https://github.com/
  ```
- BitBucket

  ```
  git config --global url.ssh://git@bitbucket.org/.insteadOf https://bitbucket.org/
  ```

That tells git to always use SSH instead of HTTPS when connecting to GitHub/BitBucket, so you'll authenticate by certificate by default, instead of being prompted for a password.

Comment: If anyone wants to look this up in [the documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html), search for `url.<base>.insteadOf`.

Comment: be wary this seems to break some things -- I've noticed some functionality of homebrew stopped working after I made this change (namely installing non-default versions / branches)

Comment: For gitlab: git config --global url.ssh://git@gitlab.com/.insteadOf https://gitlab.com/

Comment: git config --global url.ssh://git@github.com/.insteadOf https://github.com/ - warning,  i tried this, and it break all my connections with git

Comment: I _think_ that it should be git config --global url.ssh://git@github.com:.insteadOf https://github.com/, because github likes git@github.com:<USERNAME>/<REPO>.git.

(EDIT `git config --global url.git@github.com:.insteadOf https://github.com/` works in git 2.7.4 for sure.)

Comment: This is the correct answer if you are working cross platform and the other people want to use `https` because they're on windows.

Comment: Since a comment here mentioned homebrew problems it might be a good idea to remove `--global` and do this on a pr repo basis.

Comment: This doesn't work, at least for existing repositories.

Comment: @Pylinux if you're going to do it on a per-repo basis, why not just set the remote URL explicitly? This is only useful globally.

Comment: @AndrewKoster seems to work here for pulling an existing git repository.

Comment: this is much better than the accepted. in the accepted, it only tells you how to do it for a new repository. this chnges it everywhere.

Comment: This is life saver post by the way. Thanks after ~10 years.

Comment: Use `pushInsteadOf` instead of `insteadOf` to only redirect pushes. This way you don't have to enter SSH key passphrase on pull.

Answer (score 128):

The [response provided by Trevor is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11200237/how-do-i-get-git-to-default-to-ssh-and-not-https-for-new-repositories/22027731#22027731).

But here is what you can directly add in your `.gitconfig`:

```
# Enforce SSH
[url "ssh://git@github.com/"]
  insteadOf = https://github.com/
[url "ssh://git@gitlab.com/"]
  insteadOf = https://gitlab.com/
[url "ssh://git@bitbucket.org/"]
  insteadOf = https://bitbucket.org/
```

Comment: Much simpler +1

Comment: *＋1* for this trick. It is also recommended by the kernel folks. Also see [git pull](https://lists.kernelnewbies.org/pipermail/kernelnewbies/2017-November/018413.html) on the kernel newbies mailing list.

Comment: much cleaner solution - and great for _golang_ projects where "go get" defaults to https and one want to individually set urls to ssh instead e.g. for private repos etc.

Comment: For Gitlab: `[url "ssh://git@gitlab.com/"]`
 `insteadOf = https://gitlab.com/`
There is also `pushInsteadOf` if you want to affect push URL but not fetch.  Can use `git remote -v` to inspect effective URLs git is going to use.

Comment: This doesn't work, at least for existing repositories.

Comment: To be specific, modify the file via:
`$> vi ~/.gitconfig`

Comment: For GitHub Gists you may want to add `[url "git@github.com:"]` `insteadOf = https://gist.github.com/<MY_USERNAME>/`

Answer (score 11):

You need to clone in ssh not in https.

```bash
$ ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "your_email@example.com"
```

Add content of `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` to your ssh keys on github.com.

If you need to have separate keys for different hosts, you can use this script:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [ $# -lt 2 ]; then
  echo "Provide email and hostname"
  exit 1
fi

email="$1"
hostname="$2"
keypath="$HOME/.ssh/${hostname}_rsa"
ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C $email -f $keypath

if [ ! $? -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "Error when running ssh-keygen"
  exit 1
fi

exit 0
cat >> $HOME/.ssh/config <<EOF
Host $hostname
        User git
        IdentitiesOnly yes
        IdentityFile $keypath
EOF
```

and run it like

```
bash generate_ssh.sh your_email@example.com github.com
```

Change your remote url

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:user/foo.git
```

(or just edit `.git/config`)

Add content of `~/.ssh/github.com_rsa.pub` to your ssh keys on github.com

Check connection

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

Comment: This was handy for me except I had to change `Hostname $hostname *.$hostname` to `Hostname $hostname` for it to work.

Answer (score 5):

SSH File

```
~/.ssh/config file
Host *
    StrictHostKeyChecking no
    UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null
    LogLevel QUIET
    ConnectTimeout=10
Host github.com
        User git
        AddKeystoAgent yes
        UseKeychain yes
        Identityfile ~/github_rsa
```

Edit reponame/.git/config

```
[remote "origin"]
        url = git@github.com:username/repo.git
```

Answer (score 4):

FYI - I'm using this due to github no longer allowing ssh:

```
[url "git@github.com:"]
    insteadOf = https://github.com/
[url "git@gist.github.com:"]
    insteadOf = https://gist.github.com/
```

Answer (score 3):

You may have accidentally cloned the repository in https instead of ssh.
I've made this mistake numerous times on github.
Make sure that you copy the ssh link in the first place when cloning, instead of the https link.

Comment: Need to clone a new one with the ssh link

Comment: You can also change the repo link from HTTP to SSH, see the other answers.

Comment: why do they even make that the default way to clone? that's annoying

Comment: @greenie-beans I'd imagine because asking for authentication every time is a more secure default, and also most users may not have SSH set up yet for github

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Gitlab

```
git remote -v
```

you might see something like

```
https://gitlab.king.com/knight/squire.git
```

just replace king, knight , squire with your own thing. knight/squire is just the way our project has different directories then you can go

```
git remote set-url origin ssh://git@gitlab.king.com/knight/squire.git
```

git pull, or whatever and enjoy your genius

Answer (score -1):

While the other answers here directly answer the titular question (in a way that I didn't know was possible! TIL something new about `git`!) about automagically turning `https` based remotes into `git+ssh` ones, the "normal" way to do this "right" from the start is to not give `git` the `https` url.

GitHub (along with other popular git hosting services) always has a little button that lets you get the URL that `git` should clone. You just need to click the small "SSH" button:

[image: Example getting the SSH url of an existing project]

Alternatively for a new project

[image: Example getting the SSH url of an new project]

Once you select the "SSH" option, GitHub (and others) will remember (as long as you're logged in) and make it the default in the future.