# npm install failing on multi domain git repository

Tags: node.js, git, github, npm, gitlab

We have a new project and we host it in our own Gitlab server. I cloned it from

```
git@git.myacme.com:webapplication/app.git
```

successfully.

Let's say my username in gitlab is scott@myacme.com.

We also have an existing project in Github and the username I'm using is scott@yahoo.com

On the new project, we have an entry in package.json that is pointing to the existing project. Take note of the https

```
https://github.com/myacme/system-application.git
```

Now, when I execute npm install, it fails when it tries to pull the existing project in github.com. It's saying Invalid Username or Password .... Authentication failed. I think it's still using scott@myacme.com rather than scott@yahoo.com

I'm not allowed to change package.json. I was thinking of changing it to a git link instead of https but I will affect other developers. If I do, I'm thinking that it will use the settings I put in .ssh/config. I added 2 hosts, our myacme.com and github.com

What is the workaround for this? I've tried setting git config global user.name and user.email using my yahoo email address but it's still not using it. I'm out of ideas.

Here is the exact error in npm-debug.log file

```
515 error git clone --template=/Users/scott/.npm/_git-remotes/_templates --mirror https://github.com/myacme/system-application.git /Users/scott/.npm/_git-remotes/https-github-com-myacme-system-application-git-0be15bdd: remote: Invalid username or password.

515 error git clone --template=/Users/scott/.npm/_git-remotes/_templates --mirror https://github.com/myacme/system-application.git /Users/scott/.npm/_git-remotes/https-github-com-myacme-system-application-git-0be15bdd: fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/myacme/system-application.git/'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user.name is not used for authentication with https, it is only used when making a commit (for author/committer name)

What you can do is:

- for that GitHub repo, use ssh instead of https (without changing anything in the sources).
  See "[How do I get git to default to ssh and not https for new repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22027731/6309)"

  ```
  git config --global url.ssh://git@github.com/.insteadOf https://github.com/
  ```
- register your public ssh key on that GitHub repo (or at least [in your GitHub account](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/#step-4-add-your-ssh-key-to-your-account))

That way, the `git clone` would use a known authentication on GitHub (your *GitHub* `scott` account, because it has the right ssh public key).

Comment: I should have mentioned that git clone is working fine. It's an npm issue

Comment: I decided to change it to a git link in package.json and I'll just inform my teammates tomorrow. I was running out of time. I'm good now

Comment: @devwannabe  "it fails when it tries to pull the existing project in github.com." This will make it not fail. Without you having to change any url.

Comment: WOW, learned something new! That is cool! It worked! :) Thank you!