# How to fix: "fatal: unable to update url base from redirection"?

Tags: git, merge, gitlab, push

I used the following commands from the guide here:
https://zapier.com/blog/how-to-push-to-gitlab/

```
cd <mydir>
git init
git remote add origin https://gitlab.hof-university.de/yu-gi-oh/software-entwicklung-praktikum/-/tree/master
(also tried "git remote add origin https://gitlab.hof-university.de/yu-gi-oh/software-entwicklung-praktikum/    this worked when I first tried, but now I can't update with a new push)"
git add .
git status
git commit -m "first commit"
git push -u origin master (here comes the error)
```

> fatal: unable to update url base from redirection:
> asked for: https://gitlab.hof-university.de/yu-gi-oh/software-entwicklung-praktikum/-/tree/master/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack
> redirect: https://gitlab.hof-university.de/users/sign_in

What I tried:
[How do I log in using the Git terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57947268/how-do-i-log-in-using-the-git-terminal)
[fatal: unable to update url base from redirection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43910868/fatal-unable-to-update-url-base-from-redirection)
https://newbedev.com/git-push-gives-fatal-unable-to-update-url-base-from-redirection

I am new to gitlab and git and do not understand every command I use.
I just want to upload my changes I made to a folder which I uploaded with the guide from top and merge them to a newer version.

Comment: The redirect points to a "sign in" page. This suggests that you need an account (user name and password/token/whatever) and that you don't have one. Contact the University and find out how to get one.

Comment: I have an account there and can login with browser. How would I login on git bash?

Comment: `How would I login on git bash?` https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/gitlab-basics/start-using-git.html https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/index.html