# Select configuration depending on remote url

Tags: git, ssh

I have two types of Repositories on the same host with different beginning remote url:

```
github.com/foo/bar.git
github.com/foo/foo.git

github.com/bar/bar.git
github.com/bar/foo.git
```

And I want git to automatically select the identity and ssh-key depending on the current remote url. Is this even possible?

Comment: are you logged to the host with same user ?

Comment: yes, ----------

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ssh identity selection is a little bit complicated, but there are several ways to make this work.  The easiest one is this: you don't do it based on the *real GitHub* URL, but rather on a sort of a *fake* URL:

```
ssh://gh-id1/user1/repo.git
```

vs:

```
ssh://gh-id2/user2/repo.git
```

In your ssh config file, you write, for instance:

```
Host gh-id1
    Hostname github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id-user1.rsa.pub
    IdentitiesOnly yes

Host gh-id2
    Hostname github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id-user2.rsa.pub
    IdentitiesOnly yes
```

The concept here is that Git asks ssh to connect to the bogus host name `gh-id1` or `gh-id2` (you choose the actual host name, these are just examples).  When ssh gets this request, *ssh* reads its own config file and says: *Aha, you don't really want `gh-id1`, you really want `git@github.com`.*

The `git@` part comes from the `User` line in `~/.ssh/config`, which is optional.  If you don't use it in the `.ssh/config` file, you must set up the Git URL as `ssh://git@gh-id1`.

The `IdentityFile` line tells ssh which key to offer to `github.com`.  The `IdentitiesOnly` line tells ssh not to try *other* keys.  That way you're guaranteed to try only the keys listed in `IdentityFile` lines.  Git*Hub* decides whether you are you (Fred Flintstone), your wife (Wilma Flintstone), your neighbor Barney, etc., based on *which key you show them*, rather than who you really are, so by controlling which key you show them, you make sure you get identified as the person you'd like to claim to be.

Note that Git's *only role in this entire process* is that Git asks ssh to connect to some fake, bogus host name that you made up, that you control, that you list in your `.ssh/config` file.  Git itself is *not doing any authentication here:* it's pawning the entire job off onto ssh.

#### You can trigger this with `insteadOf`

To make the above work, you would in general set the *stored URL* of some repository to `ssh://gh-id1/user1/repo.git` for instance.  You could do this with `git remote set-url origin ssh://gh-id1/user1/repo.git`, or by cloning `ssh://gh-id1/user1/repo.git` initially.

Note that if your goal is to do this based on the `github.com/foo` vs `github.com/bar` parts of the URL, you can combine the above trick with Git's `insteadOf` so that you don't have to alter the *stored URL* in any way.  The `insteadOf` replacement trick is described in [the `git config` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config):

> `url.base.insteadOf`
>       Any URL that starts with this value will be rewritten to start,
> instead, with *`base`*. In cases where some site serves a large
> number of repositories, and serves them with multiple access
> methods, and some users need to use different access methods, this
> feature allows people to specify any of the equivalent URLs and
> have Git automatically rewrite the URL to the best alternative for
> the particular user, even for a never-before-seen repository on the
> site. When more than one `insteadOf` strings match a given URL, the
> longest match is used.

So here you might write:

```
git config --global url.ssh://gh-user1/foo/.insteadOf ssh://github.com/foo/
```

to transform `ssh://github.com/foo/repo.git` to `ssh://gh-user1/foo/repo.git`.  See also [How to convert `git:` urls to `http:` urls](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1722807/1256452) and [How do I get git to default to ssh and not https for new repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11200237/1256452) for related (but different) examples.

#### If that's not enough

If for some reason you need *really complex* manipulations of ssh URLs, you can direct Git to run, not the system `ssh` command, and not any Git-for-Windows provided `ssh` command, but rather your own custom-made `ssh` program.  This program *can do literally anything you like* with its arguments, as long as it winds up implementing or running `ssh` in the end.  So you could write a script or program—making it as dumb or smart as you like—that finds the URL, rewrites it, and then invokes the system ssh.

To do this, first write your own program and verify that it works:

```
my-fake-ssh ssh://github.com/foo/bar.git
my-fake-ssh git@github.com/foo/bar.git
```

and so on.  Then simply set `core.sshCommand` to `my-fake-ssh`:

```
git config --global core.sshCommand my-fake-ssh
```

Git will now run your program instead of Git's default, built-in ssh.

(To control the key you offer here, consider using `ssh`'s `-i` option.)

Comment: Thanks, but is there a way to achieve this without having to change the hostname each time?

Comment: @BierDav: not without writing your own program. If you're using ssh, Git passes the entire thing off to ssh. You can write your own substitute command and make it do whatever you want, and tell Git that instead of running the system ssh, it should run *your* not-quite-ssh. Then you can have your ssh implement whatever magical technique you can come up with.

Comment: Ok thanks, can you add this to your answer than I will accept yours

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: This will **not** pick the keys automatically

For the lazy/pragmatic programmer who wants to move fast

1. Define different ssh keys per repo
2. Before running your git command use either:

GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_for_foo_repo"

GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_for_bar_repo"

I find this simpler and I prefer the fine control

Answer (score 0):

First thanks @torek for your great answer.

I've noticed that I can also just use a shared ssh-key. For example if you work with JetBrains Space as I do you can just upload the ssh-key once for each workspace. Than the URL doesn't really matter the Space-Server decides than what account to use.

That's the solution what I personally now went with.