# npm install not picking up the correct ssh keys and unable to install private repo via ssh

Tags: node.js, git, github, npm, ssh

I'm setting up my dev environment on my new machine (m2 Mac) and have setup the `~/.gitconfig` `~/.gitconfig-work` and `~/.ssh/config` to separate my ssh keys for personal and professional use.

`~/.gitconfig`

```
[user]
  name = personal-username
  email = personal-email@gmail.com
  IdentityFile = ~/.ssh/id_rsa

[includeIf "gitdir:~/Documents/work/"]
  path = ~/.gitconfig-work

[init]
    defaultBranch = main
```

`~/.gitconfig-work`

```
[user]
name = work-username
email = work-email@work.com
IdentityFile = ~/.ssh/id_rsa_work
```

`~/.ssh/config`

```
Host github.com-personal
   HostName github.com
   User git
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
   IdentitiesOnly yes

# Work
Host github-work
   HostName github.com
   User git
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_work
   IdentitiesOnly yes
```

I add the keys to the ssh agent and cloning works fine provided I update the remote url to have the correct host field e.g `git clone git@github-work:work/work-repo.git`

Now the company that I work for have some npm packages that are the base of majority of our projects, simply running `npm install` would always work on my previous mac, but now when running npm install I get the following error

```
npm install

npm ERR! code 128
npm ERR! An unknown git error occurred
npm ERR! command git --no-replace-objects ls-remote ssh://git@github.com/work/work-private-repo.git
npm ERR! ERROR: Repository not found.
npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! and the repository exists.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

Im using `node v16.16.0` & `npm v8.11.0`, have tried with node 14 & 12 and neither worked.

Im trying to figure out the difference between the dev setup from both machines but haven't found any differences.

From the error the issue is when trying to call

```
git --no-replace-objects ls-remote ssh://git@github.com/work/work-private-repo.git
```

When I update the remote call to

```
git --no-replace-objects ls-remote ssh://git@github-work/work/work-private-repo.git
```

to match my work profile and keys, it will return a valid response.

The package.json entry for the repo which can't be found is

`"work-private-repo": "git+https://github.com/work/work-private-repo.git",`

Comment: How on earth would npm know it should switch the host? npm looks in the `package.json` and if the url for a dependency is `github.com` it will try to download it from `github.com`

Comment: ye I suppose npm shouldn't be figuring that side out, should be git + ssh, my prev setup worked fine and never had an issue similar to this, its only now that I've stumbled on this error and not really sure why its not happening automatically

Answer (score 1):

## TL;DR

I believe you want to configure `insteadOf` URL tricks.  In particular, you'll want:

```
git config --file ~/.gitconfig-work url.https://github-work/.insteadOf https://github.com/
```

for instance.  (Double check all this, it's easy to get these wrong and I might have something backwards.  Also, feel free to edit the files directly rather than using `git config`.)  Drop the `user.IdentityFile`: it's not harmful but it will confuse people.

## Long

Putting:

```
[user]
    IdentityFile = ~/.ssh/id_rsa_work
```

into a `.gitconfig` file will do absolutely nothing: no errors, no change in behavior of Git, no change in behavior of ssh.  That's because Git allows you to set arbitrary unused variable names to arbitrary values, without complaint, and then it does nothing with those variables.  `user.IdentityFile` is not used in Git.

The place you need to specify an `IdentityFile` (and preferably also set `IdentitiesOnly yes`) is in the `.ssh/config` file, so *this* part is completely correct:

> ```
> Host github.com-personal
>    HostName github.com
>    User git
>    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
>    IdentitiesOnly yes
>
> # Work
> Host github-work
>    HostName github.com
>    User git
>    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_work
>    IdentitiesOnly yes
> ```

What you need next is on the Git side: you need to make a URL that contains `github.com` refer to `github-work`, from the second section here, or `github.com-personal`, from the first.  (But the first is close enough to the defaults that it probably already works anyway: if you ask ssh to connect to `github.com`, there's no `Host` line, so you connect to `github.com` and use the default identities—including `id_rsa`.)

This is where the `insteadOf` settings come in.  According to [the `git config` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config):

> `url.<base>.insteadOf`
>
> Any URL that starts with this value will be rewritten to start, instead, with <base>. In cases where some site serves a large number of repositories, and serves them with multiple access methods, and some users need to use different access methods, this feature allows people to specify any of the equivalent URLs and have Git automatically rewrite the URL to the best alternative for the particular user, even for a never-before-seen repository on the site. When more than one insteadOf strings match a given URL, the longest match is used.

By putting these URL rewrites into the per-work and per-home settings, you can automatically replace a standard style, HTTPS-oriented URL into one of your personalized-style ssh URLs, and choose the personalized URL based on the location of the clone in your file system.

Since it's all prefix matching, you may want an entry for `ssh://github.com/` as well: as it is you're only telling Git to switch *to* ssh when using `https://github.com/`.  This way you'll personalize ssh URLs as well as HTTPS ones.

See also [How do I get git to default to ssh and not https for new repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11200237/1256452).

Comment: Thank you @torek for the response, I feel like I'm heading in the right direction Ive updated my work gitconfig to have the following 

```[url "ssh://git@github-work/"]
  insteadOf = https://github.com/```

when running npm install it doesn't seem to pick that change up, its still calling the  https endpoint instead of the ssh one.

here's the error log 

```npm ERR! Command failed: git clone --mirror -q https://github.com/work/work-repo.git /Users/me/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-40016d14/.git```

Comment: when I run the git clone command from the above comment from the terminal, it works well - so not sure why its not being replaced when running it through npm command

Comment: I'm not familiar with how npm and/or whatever extra 17 layers of crud it inserts end up invoking Git to say for sure what to do next, but the obvious attack at this point is to use system-call tracing (`strace -i` or similar) to watch for the eventual invocation of Git and see what gets passed.

Comment: I've used the verbose flag when installing npm (-ddd) and here's what I get

```npm ERR! Command failed: git clone --mirror -q https://github.com/work-org/repo.git /Users/me/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-7ff3caab/.git
npm ERR! remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021.
npm ERR! fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/work-org/repo.git/'```

Comment: my gitconfig-work profile has the following added do it ```[url "ssh://github-work/"]
 insteadOf = https://github.com/
```

Comment: just a little side note, appreciate your help, I've managed to get it working via setting https by adding the app password to the keychain, but I wanted to setup my environment to use ssh, to not need to depend on app passwords, GitHub etc...

Comment: According to the documentation, that `insteadOf` should be applied here. I wonder if there's an issue because `git clone` hasn't actually created the repository at this point, though (so that the `includeIf` clause doesn't match)...