# SPM can't find HTTPS packages but seems to resolve when I'm changing to SSH: "The repository could not be found"

Tags: swift, xcode, matlab-spm

I am trying to run a project that only ran on the original developer's machine until now and has a massive amount of Swift Packages, most of them remote but a few local as well.

As soon as I update the packages from https to ssh, they seem to resolve. However, all dependencies of those packages use https again. I'm adding all of the sub packages one by one by copying the package that errors and adding the ssh version of it, but that doesn't scale. One of the packages is TCA and it has a massive amount of sub packages alone.

[image: github.com: https://github.com/pointfreeco/swift-concurrency-extras: The repository could not be found. Make sure a valid repository exists at the specified location and try again]

`github.com: https://github.com/pointfreeco/swift-concurrency-extras: The repository could not be found. Make sure a valid repository exists at the specified location and try again`

Once I noticed one of the issues was a completely missing package. I suspect it was a local package that never got included to the git repo for some reason.

- Is there some kind of way to make everything ssh?
- Is it possible to keep resolving all packages instead of stopping at the first error?
- Is there any way to find and/or resolve the root cause of this error?

I checked in a separate project if any of the offending packages refused to load over https and that worked just fine, so there's no weird port blocking rule on my network or something.

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/troubleshooting-ssh/using-ssh-over-the-https-port

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get git to default to ssh and not https for new repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11200237/how-do-i-get-git-to-default-to-ssh-and-not-https-for-new-repositories)

Comment: I just answered my own questions. I still don't completely grasp the issue, I wish I had deeper error logs than what Xcode gives me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After replacing all packages with SSH and adding all of their dependencies in SSH as well it worked.

I restarted my computer for the third time and now it seems a bit more stable in other projects with less dependencies.

I will try to update my answer once I learn more, for now, the only solution seems to be to keep restarting your computer and/or changing EVERY dependency to SSH.